# Sql between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE id != 1 AND
      (event_date BETWEEN '20/06/2015' AND '01/07/2015')
ORDER BY the_date
```

The result is 0.
If I try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE id != 1 AND
      (event_date BETWEEN '20/06/2015' AND '29/06/2015')
ORDER BY the_date
```

It works.

What is the problem with the difference between tow month (Juny and July).

Thanks.

Comment: in the first query you are selecting from `some_table` and in the second one you are selecting from `events`. could that be related?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're comparing these dates lexicographically. Assuming that `event_date` is a `date` column, use [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the string literals to dates:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     some_table
WHERE    id != 1 AND
         (event_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('20/06/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') AND 
                             STR_TO_DATE('01/07/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'))
ORDER BY the_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Write date constants in the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE id != 1 AND
      event_date BETWEEN '2015-06-20' AND '2015-07-01'
ORDER BY the_date
```

Comment: But the dates in my db are in this format: 10/07/2015

Comment: @DorBenZaken . . . You  should be using `date` as the data type for storing dates in the database.  The output representation is not important.  If you are using strings to store dates, then fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses the following data types for saving a date:

DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD

DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Try changing the date format